# AngularJS stop function in a draggable directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following draggable directive, I made the drag function in a controller in a seprate file. So how can I call this function on drag stop.
I've tried the below code but didn't work with me .

```js
MainApp.directive('draggable', ['$rootScope','$parse', function ($rootScope,$parse) {
    var draggableConfig = {};
    return {

        restrict: 'A',
    
        link: function postLink (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.draggable({
                stop: function (evt, ui) {
                    $parse(scope[attrs.onDrag])();
                }
            })
            }};
}]);
```

```html
  <div resizable on-resize="resize(1)" draggable on-drag="drag()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$parse returns a function which has to be evaluated against a scope.

So you should do it this way:

```
$parse(attrs.onDrag)(scope)
```

That assuming the function `drag()` is accessible from that scope. Otherwise, you *may* be able to access it using `scope.$parent`.